# Converting columns in dataframe within list?

Tags: r, lapply

What is the best way to convert a specific column in each list object to a specific format?

For instance, I have a list with four objects (each of which is a data frame) and I want to change column 3 in each data.frame from double to integer?

I'm guessing something along the line of lapply but I didn't know what specific synthax to use. I was trying:

```
lapply(df,function(x){as.numeric(var1(x))})
```

but it wasn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: `listdf %>%  map(~mutate_at(.x, 3, as.numeric)) %>% str` use `library(tidyverse)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `lapply` works well here:

```
lapply(listofdfs, function(df) {       # loop through each data.frame in list
    df[ , 3] <- as.integer(df[ , 3])   # make the 3rd column of type integer
    df                                 # return the new data.frame
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an alternative to C. Braun's answer.

You can also use `map()` function from the `purr` library.

Input:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3), b =c(4, 5, 6), d = c(7, 8, 9))
myList <- list(df, df, df)
myList
```

Method:

```
map(myList, ~(.x %>% mutate_at(vars(3), funs(as.integer(.)))))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    1.    4.     7
2    2.    5.     8
3    3.    6.     9

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    1.    4.     7
2    2.    5.     8
3    3.    6.     9

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    1.    4.     7
2    2.    5.     8
3    3.    6.     9
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the first answer is fine but good to have an alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
dlist2 <- lapply(dlist,function(x){
  y <- x
  y[,coltochange] <- as.numeric(x[,coltochange])
  return(y)
}    )
```

Simple example:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(c("1","2","3","4",NA),c(1:5)),stringsAsFactors = F)
typeof(data[,1]) #character
dlist <- list(data,data,data)
coltochange <- 1
dlist2 <- lapply(dlist,function(x){
  y <- x
  y[,coltochange] <- as.numeric(x[,coltochange])
  return(y)
}    )
typeof(dlist[[1]][,1]) #character
typeof(dlist2[[1]][,1]) #double
```